# WooCommerce + PayPal

Tags: paypal, woocommerce

I have installed the latest version of WooCommerce with their Subscriptions Plugin and I am trying to link it to our PayPal Account. Subscription Creation's, refunds, and everything else are working properly. However, when a customer cancels their account from the My Account page or if I try and cancel a subscription from the Subscriptions page in the Wordpress backend, the subscription is never cancelled on the PayPal side.

**Here is the error from the log:**

```
07-07-2014 @ 12:23:36 - Calling PayPal to change_subscription_status has Failed: 
                        The profile ID is invalid
07-07-2014 @ 12:26:24 - Checking IPN response is valid via https://www.paypal.com/
                         cgi-bin/webscr...
07-07-2014 @ 12:26:24 - IPN Request: Array(
```

Any ideas?

Comment: So I made a discovery ... If I cancel the subscription in PayPal ... It will show cancelled in the WooCommerce Store. However, if I cancel the subscription from the Store or from My Account ... It does not cancel the subscription in PayPal. Any ideas?

Comment: which plugin is use for PayPal subscription

Comment: For this purpose you have to use extention named Woocommerce Subscription which is premiume woocommerce extention for more detail you can follow this link:- https://docs.woothemes.com/document/subscriptions/payment-gateways/